# How often does a PageSpeed Insights score get updated?

Tags: google-pagespeed

I'm curious to know how frequently PageSpeed Insights, or maybe I should say Lighthouse, refreshes it's data, or does it generate the score live at the time the user submits the URL for analysis? So, if I run an analysis of a URL at 9am, then I push a bunch of improvements to that page into production at 10am, how soon could I expect to see those changes reflected in my PageSpeed Insights score?

Answer (score 0):

Changes are reflected immediately in the 'lab' tests (i.e. when you enter your URL and press 'analyze') and they do not cache anything so any changes will be reflected instantly.

If your site has enough data for real world test information these are updated every 1-7 days depending on your traffic.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly Graham, this is really useful to know.